# filter scala map of key as string and value as set of objects

Tags: scala

Below is `filterSetofSource` which has first two words of a string as the key of the map and last word as the value of the `state` field in an Item case class. We have to traverse `filterSetofSource` and if first two words matches key of the map and the last word matches state then only keep those key and the matched value of Item in Set.

```
val filterSetofSource = Set("apple of kashmir", "apple of jammu")

val map = Map("apple of" -> Set(Item(
                               location = Some(Map("state" -> "kashmir"))
                            ),Item(
                               location = Some(Map("state" -> "himachal"))
                            )
             )
```

in the above scenario output should be as below:

```
Map("apple of" -> Set(Item(
                           location = Some(Map("state" -> "kashmir"))
                          )
             )
   )
```

Being new to Scala I am not able to implement the logic so seeking help.

Comment: @jwvh it is a case class which encapsulates location

Comment: It would be good if you included the necessary code to reproduce this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces the result you're looking for.

```
val locals = filterSetofSource.map(_.split("\\s+").lift(2))
                              .filter(_.nonEmpty)

val result = map.map { case (k, v) =>
  k -> v.filter(itm => locals(itm.location.map(_("state"))))
}
```

This makes two, perhaps dangerous, assumptions:

1. The 3rd word (if it exists) of each `filterSetofSource` entry is always the location part.
2. The `Item.location` `Map` always has a `"state"` key.

I've got to say that this is the most ridiculous hodgepodge collection of data structures I've encountered in a long time.